# std::vector vs std::stack

Tags: c++, stl, stack, stdvector

What is the difference between `std::vector` and `std::stack`?

Obviously vectors can delete items within the collection (albeit much slower than list) whereas the stack is built to be a LIFO-only collection.

*However, are stacks faster for end-item manipulation? Is it a linked list or dynamically re-allocated array?*

I can't find much information about stacks, but if I'm picturing them correctly (they are similar to an actual thread stack; push, pop, etc. - along with that `top()` method) then they seem perfect for window-stacking management.

Comment: The former is a container, the latter is a container _adapter_.

Comment: "albeit much slower than list"  Theoretically, yes.  Practically, no.  `vector` will outperform `list` for almost every use case.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis for deleting records in the middle of large vector datasets? Isn't that much slower than lists, which are double-listed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the major difference between a vector and a stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785841/what-is-the-major-difference-between-a-vector-and-a-stack)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

A `stack` is not a container; it is a container *adapter*. It has a `vector`, `deque` or similar container that it stores as a member that actually holds the elements. Remember: it is declared as:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::deque<T>
> class stack;
```

All `stack` does is limit the user interface to this internal container. The performance characteristics of the operations are exactly whatever the underlying container's performance characteristics are.

Comment: I think I understand what is meant by the term `container adapter`, still wondering though if there is specific definition. Is there a list of what can be called `container adapters`
 anywhere?