# What are the advantages and disadvantages of using std::stack instead of just deque, vector or list

Tags: c++, stl, stack, containers

I am writing a very simple std::stack using vector as its underlying container. I realized that I could replace all the push(), pop() and top() functions with push_back(), pop_back() and back() of the vector container.

My questions are: why to use a container adaptor when the controlled use of the underlying container is enough? Why not to use just a deque, vector or list? There will be waste of memory or processing time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486487/stdvector-vs-stdstack Specifically, "All stack does is limit the user interface to this internal container. The performance characteristics of the operations are exactly whatever the underlying container's performance characteristics are."

Comment: It's a good point, I hadn't seen it, but is still very superficial. I still don't know when to use one over the other. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When your code says `std::stack` it's clear to the reader what operations they need on the container... it communicates and documents while enforcing that no other operations are used.  It may help them quickly form an impression of the algorithmic logic in your code.  It's then easy to substitute other implementations that honour the same interface.

It's a bit like using `std::ifstream` instead of `std::fstream` - you can read and write with `std::fstream`, but whomever reads your code will need to consider more possible uses you put the stream to before realising that it's only being used for reading; you'd be wasting their mental effort.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, basically, there are no difference in memory usage or processing time using the std::stack?

Comment: @pbruno: if you enable normal levels of optimisation (e.g. `g++ /O2`, `cl.exe /O2`...) the stack wrapper functions should be inlined with no net performance or memory cost.