# Why there is no supported iterators for some STL containers (Stack, Queue, Priority Queue)?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Across all types of iterators, why there is no supported pattern for `stack`, `queue` and `priority_queue` STL containers ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){

    std::stack<int> values;
    std::stack<int> valuesCopy;

    values.push(98);
    values.push(11);
    values.push(14);
    values.push(17);
    values.push(20);

    std::for_each( /* How can i manage this in a alternative way */,
                      [&](int value) mutable throw() -> void{ /* Process */ ;} );

    std::copy(/* Same for this */,std::back_inserter(valuesCopy));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by supported pattern?

Comment: @rekkalmd It is because these data structures have access only to the top element.

Comment: Read [What are Containers/Adapters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873802/what-are-containers-adapters-c) and [std::vector vs std::stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486487/stdvector-vs-stdstack). And, you can always use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: only being able to access the top element is what makes a stack a stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The three are not classic containers, but rather *[container adaptors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Container_adaptors)*. They do not need to support the iteration. A quote from the "C++ Programming Language" book:

> Container adaptors provide specialized access to underlying
>   containers.

They are:

> intended to be used only through their specialized interfaces. In particular, the STL
>   container adaptors do not offer direct access to their underlying container. They **do not offer iterators** or subscripting.